# uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < line one js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have seen many questions similar to this one on here but none of them seem to fix the problem I am having.
I keep getting the following error-

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

It says the error is in line one of the js file but the sources only shows a red line on line one of the html file.

Should also mention it is running on a go server.

Thanks a mil!

Here is my HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Sourcing jquery and ajax -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--external script.js file-->
    <script type = "text/JavaScript" src="ChatBot.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 65px;
            padding-bottom: 100px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Eliza chat bot</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="list-group">
  <div class="fixed-bottom bg-dark p-2">
                <div class="container">
                    <div>
                        <ul class="list-group"></ul>
                    </div>
                    <form action="/Chat" method="GET">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userInput" placeholder="Talk to eliza...">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </ul>  </div>
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    
</body>

</html>
```

and here is my js

```js
const form = $("#userInput");
const listItem = $("#list-group");

//add the keypress function for when the user types an input for eliza to compute

$(document).ready(()=>{

form.keypress(function(event){

    const keyCodes = {
    ENTER : 13
}

let keyCode = event.keyCode;

    //for enter
    if(event.keyCode !=  keyCodes.ENTER){ 
        return;
    }

      event.preventDefault(); 

      const input = form.val();
      form.val(" ");

       listItem.append("<li class='list-group-item list-group-item-success'>"+"User : " + input + "</li>");

      // GET/POST
    const queryParams = {"userInput" : input }
    $.get("/Chat", queryParams)
        .done(function(response){
            var nextListItem = "<li class='list-group-item list-group-item-info'>"+"ELiza : " + response + "</li>";
            setTimeout(function(){
                listItem.append(nextListItem)
            }, 1000);//set timeout to give wait to response
        }).fail(function(){
            var nextListItem = "<li class='list-group-item list-group-item-danger' >Sorry I'm not home right now.</li>";
            list.append(nextListItem);
        });
});
 
  });
```

Comment: Silly question, I guess, but are you running ES6 on your server?

Comment: Why is this question tagged go? It doesn't appear to have anything at all to do with go.

Comment: create a plunker/fiddler/SO snippet reproducing above mentioned error

Comment: @Snowmonkey no its just running on local host. I have a go file that serves the above html file

Comment: Not certain, but I'm wondering if your `script type "text/JavaScript"` may be causing this.  Should be `"text/javascript"` -- but in HTML5 should be omitted altogether, just use `<script>` without a type attribute.

Comment: On second thought, no; if my last comment was correct that would cause the script to fail but not with that particular error.   (You should still remove the incorrect attribute, but it's probably not what's causing this problem.)  I'm pretty sure @dotDeeka is correct that you're one way or another getting html where you expect javascript, perhaps as part of a 404 response (is the filename correct? It's ChatBot.js and not chatbot.js?)

Comment: @Adrian note the line "Should also mention it is running on a go server".

Comment: @Snowmonkey does that mean anything at all? I'm not aware of anything that could be described as "running on a Go server". This static HTML and JS could be served by a Go app, but being static, that has exactly zero impact - it could just as well be served by Nginx or IIS. The go tag does not seem to apply to this question in any way at all.

Comment: @Adrian I agree, but given that the OP stated the go server, the OP gave it the go tag. Pointless, as i doubt the issue is go-related. Kind of a red herring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your webserver happen to have a rule where if the requested resources is not found it will default to serving the index.html file? This is a popular configuration for Single Page Applications.

If that is the case, if the server can not find the js file requested it will serve the contents of the html file, which the browser will try parse as JavaScript. Since the first character on the first line of the html file is `<` you'll get a syntax error since that is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: I am not sure as I am using a go file to serve that html page on my local host. It is very basic with just a main function - func main() {
 // handles root page
 http.HandleFunc("/", requestHandler)

 //handle /chat page
 http.HandleFunc("/Chat", chatHandler)
 http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}// and this as the requestHandler// - func requestHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
 //serve the homepage.html file
 http.ServeFile(w, r, "ChatBot.html")
}// the chatHandler currently does nothing