# unexpected token error '<' on jquery.min.js and bootstrap.js

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

[image]

I got this error over night literally out of nowhere. It was working fine last night but I opened the browser this morning and this thing happened. It seems like there is something wrong with the static path. css files weren't applied as well (by the way, I'm using Spring Boot)

I've been working on this several hours but I couldn't figure out yet.

Comment: Have you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630006/error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: I checked that out already but it wasn't the issue. thank you

Comment: Maybe all your script files have broken link? Can your check it? Are you working on your project live?

Comment: All the script files are working fine. it seems like static folder path issue. css files also weren't applied.

Comment: You can check all the folder path of each files, You may try to right click each file from the console log(your screenshot) then open a new tab to see if the file exists on that path location.

Comment: Given that **all** of your scripts have this error, could it be a variant of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47399037/11981207)? As little_coder suggested, try clicking on the "jquery-1.1.0.min.js:1" link in your console and see what comes up.

Comment: it worked! I clicked on the error message earlier as you and little_coder suggested  and I saw the error on <!DOCTYPE html>. but I didn't know why there is an error. I changed `@GetMapping` last night from` @GetMapping("/")` to `@GetMapping` somehow I thought Spring boot can track default request without ("/"). Thank you so much @Kei and @little_coder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kei and little_coder helped me to figure this out. go check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398550/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-line-one-js/47399037#47399037)

> If that is the case, if the server can not find the js file requested it will serve the contents of the html file, which the browser will try parse as JavaScript. Since the first character on the first line of the html file is < you'll get a syntax error since that is not valid JavaScript.

In a nutshell, make sure if you sent the right request to html file, otherwise webserver won't be able to find script file and parse the html file which contains the script file instead.

In my case, I changed @GetMapping to @GetMapping("/")
SpringBoot did find html file but as I clicked one of those error message I could see this

[image]

I clicked `jquery-1.1.0.min.js:1` but it returned whole html file instead of script code.

when your webserver couldn't find the requested resources (like javascript, css) , Springboot (in my case) seems like taking you to index.html or some other default html file. so the answer of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398550/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-line-one-js/47399037#47399037) explain a lot